# How to Arrange DataRow Sequences in datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have column in  DataTable with RowsOrder postion?

In rowsorder postion data is-
Postion in Column:
1
1a
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
11
2a
11a
12
13a
14
5
2
12b
14c
abc

I want to show Postion

1
1a
2
2a
5
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
11
11a
12
12b
13a
14
14a
14c
.....
..
100
100a
101b
.....
1011a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IComparable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("AlphaNumeric", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "4" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "6" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "7" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "8" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "9" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "10" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "11" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "11a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "12" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "13a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "14" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "5" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "12b" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "14c" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "abc" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1011a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "101b" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "100a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "100" });


            DataTable sorted = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => new SortAlphaNumeric(x.Field<string>("AlphaNumeric"))).CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
    public class SortAlphaNumeric : IComparable<SortAlphaNumeric>
    {
        public int? number { get;set;}
        public string alpha { get;set;}

        public SortAlphaNumeric(string alphaNumeric)
        {
            string pattern = @"(?'number'\d*)(?'alpha'.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(alphaNumeric, pattern);

            string numberStr = match.Groups["number"].Value;
            alpha = match.Groups["alpha"].Value;

            if (numberStr.Length > 0)
            {
                number = (int?)int.Parse(numberStr);
            }


        }
        public int CompareTo(SortAlphaNumeric other)
        {
            if (number == null)
            {
                if (other.number == null)
                {
                    return alpha.CompareTo(other.alpha);
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1 ;  //other is greater than this
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (other.number == null)
                {
                    return -1; //this is greater than other
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.number == other.number)
                    {
                        return this.alpha.CompareTo(other.alpha);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return ((int)this.number).CompareTo((int)other.number);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```